# Losing Time When Saving to Database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm using Java and hibernate on a web server to save to an Oracle SQL database. I create a Java `Date` object, but for some reason by the time it makes it to the database, it only has the date and not the time. For instance, the Date object will say "Dec 10, 2012 1:23:45 PM" but in the database it only says "10-DEC-12"

Any idea why this would happen? Below is an example of how the date is created and saved.

service.java

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Nos nos = new Nos();
nos.setTimeReceived( new Date() );
session.save( nos );

tx.commit();
```

Nos.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nos")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Nos
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="timereceived")
    private java.util.Date timeReceived;

// getters and setters
```

Comment: This is documented behaviour. A `java.sql.Date` does not contain a time (read the Javadocs). You need to use a `Timestamp`

Comment: ... Although this begs the question, what's the type _in the database_?  If it's only a `date` type there, it's not going to matter what you do in Java (it may also be important to know the RDBMS as well).

Comment: Very good point @Clockwork-Musem, that didn't occur to me.

Comment: But...I thought I read that a SQL DATE does contain time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`, which corresponds to a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

As per [the `TemporalType` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html), `TemporalType.DATE` maps to a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), which as you're seeing as no time component:

> To conform with the definition of SQL `DATE`, the millisecond values wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.